# Running Hadoop beside Marathon and Mesos

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-compose, mesos, marathon

I have three nodes with docker installed on  them, one master and two slaves and want to run Mesos,marathon and hadoop on docker. I have these docker compose files:
This docker compose is for master node to run Mesos and Marathon:

```
 version: '3.7'
 services:
  zookeeper:
    image: hadoop_marathon_mesos_flink_2
    command: >
         sh -c "
         echo zookeeper && /home/zookeeper-3.4.14/bin/zkServer.sh 
         restart && 
         sleep 30 && /home/mesos-1.7.2/build/bin/mesos-master.sh 
        --ip=10.32.0.1 --hostname=10.32.0.1 --roles=marathon,flink |
        /home/marathon-1.7.189-48bfd6000/bin/marathon --master 
       10.32.0.1:5050 --zk zk://10.32.0.1:2181/marathon 
       --hostname 10.32.0.1 --webui_url 10.32.0.1:8080 
       --logging_level debug"
   privileged: true
   network_mode: "bridge"
   environment:
     WEAVE_CIDR: 10.32.0.1/12
     ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
     ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
     ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
     ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 10
     ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 5
     ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: 10.32.0.1:2888:3888
     MESOS_CLUSTER: Yekta
     LIBPROCESS_IP: 10.32.0.1
     MESOS_QUORUM: 1
     MESOS_LOG_DIR: /var/log/mesos
     MESOS_WORK_DIR: /var/run/mesos
     MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT: 5mins
     HOSTNAME: 10.32.0.1
     MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY: /usr/local/lib/libmesos.so
     MESOS_DOCKER_SOCKET: /var/run/weave/weave.sock
  volumes:
   - /home/cfms11/.ssh:/root/.ssh
  expose:
   - 2181
   - 2888
   - 3888
   - 5050
   - 4040
   - 7077
   - 8080
   - 9000
   - 50070
   - 50090
 ports:
   - 2181:2181
   - 2888:2888
   - 3888:3888
   - 5050:5050
   - 4040:4040
   - 7077:7077
   - 8080:8080
   - 9000:9000
   - 50070:50070
   - 50090:50090
 networks:
  default:
   external:
    name: weave
```

Docker compose in slave nodes:

```
  version: '3.7'
  services:
   slave:
    image: hadoop_marathon_mesos_flink_2
    command: sh -c "/home/mesos-1.7.2/build/bin/mesos-slave.sh 
    --master=10.32.0.1:5050 --work_dir=/var/run/mesos  
    --systemd_enable_support=false"
    privileged: true
    network_mode: "weave"
    environment:
      WEAVE_CIDR: 10.32.0.1/12
      MESOS_RESOURCES: ports(*):[11000-11999]
      LIBPROCESS_IP: 10.32.0.2
      MESOS_HOSTNAME: 10.32.0.2
      MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT: 5mins #also in Dockerfile
      MESOS_LOG_DIR: /var/log/mesos
      MESOS_WORK_DIR: /var/run/mesos
      MESOS_LOGGING_LEVEL: INFO
    volumes:
     - /home/spark/.ssh:/root/.ssh
   expose:
    - 5051
   ports:
    - 5051:5051
   networks:
    default:
     external:
      name: weave
```

After running docker compose files, marathon and mesos are run without any problems. Then, I must enter to the container which is made with docker compose and run hadoop too. Therefore, I do these stages:
In each node:

```
  sudo docker-compose ps
```

I copy the name of output of above command.

```
  sudo docker exec -it "the_name" /bin/bash
```

After entering to that container in Master node, I run these commands:

```
  cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
  chmod -R 750 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys 
  chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
  chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
  chown -R root ~/.ssh/
  chgrp -R root ~/.ssh/
  service ssh restart
```

Also, I run these commands in slave containers:

```
  chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
  chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
  chown -R root ~/.ssh/
  chgrp -R root ~/.ssh/
  service ssh restart
```

After doing those works, I can run hadoop with this command:

```
  /opt/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

But, it is not started. I get this error:

> Starting namenodes on [compose-weave-ok-for-master-node_zookeeper_1.weave.local]
>
> compose-weave-ok-for-master-node_zookeeper_1.weave.local: ERROR: Cannot set priority of namenode process 1985
>
> Starting datanodes
>
> Starting secondary namenodes [compose-weave-ok-for-master-node_zookeeper_1.weave.local]

I think it is because ID Container is not in /etc/hosts. In fact, /etc/hosts is in following:

```
 # created by Weave - BEGIN
 # container hostname
 10.32.0.1   compose-weave-ok-for-master-node_zookeeper_1.weave.local 
 compose-weave-ok-for-master-node_zookeeper_1

 # static names added with --add-host

 # default localhost entries
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  ::1             ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  fe00::0         ip6-localnet
  ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
  ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
# created by Weave - EN
```

Would any one please tell me, how I can run hadoop beside Marathon and Mesos?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please be careful to have the same hadoop path on each node. 
Also, put the Container ID on your Hosts file and run Hadoop again. I think it solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I put the container ID in Hosts file and it made **Namenode**, but it did not make **Datanode** on slave nodes.